# google cloud storage sample not working

Tags: google-cloud-storage

anyone else having an issue getting google cloud storage API sample to work?
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/overview#Complete_Sample_App

I followed all the directions which are very straight forward. You simply paste the code form the sample and it should work. However you do have to update your bucket names. I am updating this line

```
# TODO: Change to a bucket your app can write to.
READ_PATH = '/gs/bucket/obj'
```

to

```
READ_PATH = 'gs://mybucketname'
```

it does not work?
I updated it as such because that's how i access my bucket via gsutil

Anyone got this to work?

Answer (score 2):

In the Files API, the path does **not** follow the gs:// URL scheme. As the example states, you need to make it:

```
/gs/mybucketname/myobjectname
```

Comment: i tried that at first but it did not work. I think it may be a permissions thing. My app is set to have edit permissions.

Comment: anyone have trouble with this. I guess simply I just need to see an example of how to write the bucket naming?